# Having issues with a function game. Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm tasked with creating a snap-crackle game from a function. I have a few issues. I'm able to get what I intended to get from steps 1 and 2, the last step, I'm suppose to create a prompt that will ask the user for a value that will be used in the function to deliver the result of the game . The final result I should have for example, if someone entered the number 12 at the prompt, it should print 12 for max value, and the string Snap, 2, Snap, 4, SnapCrackle, 6, Snap, 8, Snap, Crackle, Snap, 12.

However as you can see it's my code is causing some issues. It's showing multiple snap-crackle strings, it showing two max values, and one of them is null. I don't know how I can change maxValue variable to now be the highestNumber variable that is asked in the prompt. There's no way to tie that highestNumber value back into the function as maxValue, and it seems the code is reading two different games instead of only one. I'll will post the instructions and my code so far, to make things understandable and apologies for the long post, trying best ti explain what is suppose to be going on here.

> **Step One**
> Write a function named snapCrackle that takes one parameter: maxValue. This function should loop through 1 up to maxValue (inclusive) and build a string with the following conditions:
>
> - If a number is odd, concatenate "Snap, " to the end of the string.
> - If a number is a multiple of 5, concatenate "Crackle, " to the end of the string.
> - If a number is both odd and a multiple of 5 concatenate "SnapCrackle, " to the end of the string.
> - If a number is neither odd or a multiple of 5, concatenate the number and ", " to the end of the string.
>
> **Step Two**
> Write a function called render that takes in two parameters: text, and maxValue.
> This function should print the game to the page using document.write().
>
> **Step Three**
> Finally, create a prompt that asks the user for the max value.
> Assign the result of the prompt to a variable, highestNumber
> Then call snapCrackle(highestNumber) and assign the result to a variable, result.
> Finally, call render(result, highestNumber);
> This will render your game to the page

```
let maxValue = 12;
let newArray = [];
let s = " Snap";
let c = " Crackle"; 
let x = " Snapcrackle";

function snapCrackle() {
 for (let i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
   if (i % 2 !== 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
     newArray.push(x);
   } else if (i % 2 !== 0) {
     newArray.push(s);
   } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
     newArray.push(c);
   } else {
     newArray.push(i);
   }
 }
 return newArray;
} 


let text = snapCrackle();

function render (text, maxValue){
 document.write(`
 <h1>Snap Crackle!</h1>
 <h3>Max Value ${maxValue}</h3>
 <p>${text}</p>
 `);
}

console.log(render(text,maxValue));

let highestNumber = prompt("What is the highest number?");
snapCrackle(highestNumber);
let result = snapCrackle(highestNumber);
console.log(render(result,highestNumber));
```

Comment: Hi Corey, if you would be able to simplify a bit about what you are asking here that would be helpful in terms of providing meaningful feedback. On the other hand, this is a classic "Fizz-buzz" type of problem, so there are other resources to help you with the concept as a general preference.
https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/fizzbuzz-in-too-much-detail/#:~:text=FizzBuzz%20is%20a%20very%20simple,numbers%20from%201%20to%20100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a homework assignment so I'm only going to point out the things that are wrong in terms of *how* you're using the function. I'm not 100% sure if the logic inside your function is correct or not, hopefully you can figure that part out on your own.

Your function `snapCrackle` doesn't take an argument so it's always using the `maxValue` declared on line 1 and never using the value you put into the prompt.

You're also running the function twice which both calls are referencing the same array (declared on line 2). So regardless of what you enter into the prompt it just runs the function as if `maxValue` is 12 and it runs it twice.

You can fix this by removing your declarations on lines 1 and 2. And then modifying your function to look like this:

```
function snapCrackle(maxValue) {
  const newArray = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
      newArray.push(x);
    } else if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      newArray.push(s);
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      newArray.push(c);
    } else {
      newArray.push(i);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Now instead of running the function twice, only run it after you've gotten the number from the prompt like this:

```
function render(text, maxValue) {
  document.write(`
 <h1>Snap Crackle!</h1>
 <h3>Max Value ${maxValue}</h3>
 <p>${text}</p>
 `);
}

let highestNumber = prompt("What is the highest number?");
snapCrackle(highestNumber);
let result = snapCrackle(highestNumber);
console.log(render(result, highestNumber));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked!! I appreciate that, and I understand now what I was doing wrong. This helped me a lot more understanding functions.

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: One more question please, since we took the variable away for text =, how does the function know what ${text} references? How does it know to reference the newArray, array?

Comment: So `${text}` is an argument passed to your `render` function. The value will be whatever you pass. When you call `render(result, highestNumber))` at the end of your script `result` is the result returned from `snapCrackle` which is an array. Since you're printing that array as HTML it just gets converted to a string automatically

`newArray` is declared from inside the `snapCrackle` function that's why it's available.